# "Exporting" Plot Theme "Classic"

Tags: plotting, visualization, implementation-details, plot-themes

I really like the 3D plots in Mathematica with the `PlotTheme` option set to `"Classic"`. I wonder if there's a way to export the colormap (RGB, alpha-array) for use in some other open-source software, and also which function is used to choose the color.

I'd be very glad, if you can give me a (hint to a) solution.

TIA

Comment: The `"Classic"` color scheme for `Plot3D` colors the polygons white and uses custom lighting to give the illusion of different colors.

Comment: Hi Chip, thanks for your answer! Is there a way to reproduce this effect and get similar plots with matlab/matplotlib/mayavi

Comment: I've turned my comment into an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `"Classic"` theme for `Plot3D` colors the surface white and uses custom lighting. It can be recreated with these options:

```
Plot3D[Sin[x + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}, 
  PlotStyle -> White, 
  Lighting -> {
    {"Ambient", RGBColor[0.312, 0.188, 0.4]}, 
    {"Directional", RGBColor[0.8, 0, 0], ImageScaled[{2, 0, 2}]},
    {"Directional", RGBColor[0, 0.8, 0], ImageScaled[{2, 2, 2}]}, 
    {"Directional", RGBColor[0, 0, 0.8], ImageScaled[{0, 2, 2}]}
  }
]
```

[image]

I'm not sure how to export lighting or recreate it in other applications though.

Comment: The explicit settings for `"Classic"` are also in [the docs](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/ChangeTheLightingOfPlots.html).